# Explicit namespaces for non-exported functions within same R package - best practice

Tags: r, namespaces, documentation

I have an R package (`MyPackage`) that has some exported (using `@export`) and some non-exported functions.  If I call a non-exported function from elsewhere in the package, what is the most appropriate way to reference it? For example, given the following code:

```
#' @export
f1 <- function(){
  f2()
  }

f2 <- function(){
  print('hello')
  }
```

When I run linting on the package I get the warning:

```
no visible global function definition for 'f2'
```

I could use `MyPackage:f2` but my understanding was that this isn't necessary. I do not expect to get the error 'no visible global function definition' for a function within the same package. What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: could you please describe your steps in more details, `lintr` doesn't give me such a warning.

Comment: a minimal package using these functions passes R CMD and `lintr::lint_package()`, see [this repo](https://github.com/D-Se/globalbinding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As myself and others have mentioned, your code does not produce such a warning.

In terms of best practices, don't use `MyPackage:::f2`. As mentioned [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-include-internal-functions/38654).

> A function is not exported to user is not present in the NAMESPACE. If
> you use roxygen, putting @export tag ONLY for the function you want to
> export will do the job.

As you did, just using the `@export` tag for the functions you want to make available, and not for the internal functions, is the way to go. You should just decorate your internal functions with a few `roxygen` comments, then decide whether you want to create a manual page for this function or not.

If you don't wish to create a manual page for `f2`, you should use the `#' @noRd` tag. ([source](https://blog.r-hub.io/2019/12/12/internal-functions/))

```
#' Internal function printing "hello"
#' @description A function that prints the text "hello".
#' @noRd
f2 <- function(){
  print('hello')
  }
```

If you wanted to create a manual page for `f2`, but to exclude it from the index of the manual, you could use `@keywords internal`, which works even with `f1` or basically any function that you wouldn't want too visible in your manual.

```
#' Internal function printing "hello"
#' @description A function that prints the text "hello".
#' @keywords internal
f2 <- function(){
  print('hello')
  }
```